# Multiple nodes providing same service, which one will get through (many to one services)

Tags: ros, rosservice, call-service, laser-assembler, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying a very simple task. I have a 2D laser scanner and 3D velodyne laser on my robot and I want to create an assembled point cloud which includes data from both lasers in one point cloud. I am trying to have [laser_assembler](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_assembler) package do all the work with `laser_scan_assembler` and `point_cloud2_assembler` nodes, which both provide services of same name `/assembled_point_cloud` which is of the same type sensor_msgs::PointCloud.

The problem I'm facing is that my `temp_service_call_node` only subscribes to one service (the one provided by point_cloud2_assembler), and gets no data from laser_scan_assembler. Also, if I kill the velodyne node, so that no point cloud2 data is published for point_cloud2_assembler, it doesn't change anything. `/assembled_point_cloud` which instead of showing only 2D laser scan data when no point cloud2 data is available, keeps subscribing to the `point_cloud2_assembler` which doesn't give any data.

Is there anything I'm missing or a different approach that I can try?

Please see code for reference-

Here's my launch file:

```
<launch>
    <node type="laser_scan_assembler" pkg="laser_assembler" name="laser_scan_assembler">
        <remap from="scan" to="/laser/scan"/>
        <remap from="assemble_scans" to="assembled_point_cloud"/>
        <param name="max_scans" type="int" value="1" />
        <param name="fixed_frame" type="string" value="base_link" />
    </node>
    
    <node type="point_cloud_assembler" pkg="laser_assembler" name="point_cloud_assembler">
        <remap from="cloud" to="/laser/point_cloud"/>
        <remap from="assemble_scans" to="assembled_point_cloud"/>
        <param name="max_clouds" type="int" value="1" />
        <param name="fixed_frame" type="string" value="base_link" />
    </node>
        
     <node type="point_cloud2_assembler" pkg="laser_assembler" name="point_cloud2_assembler">
        <remap from="cloud" to="/laser/point_cloud2"/>
        <remap from="assemble_scans" to="assembled_point_cloud"/>
        <param name="max_clouds" type="int" value="1" />
        <param name="fixed_frame" type="string" value="base_link" />
    </node>
</launch>
```

temp_service_call.cpp file:

```
void publishPointCloud2()
{
    //Wait for service to start
    ros::service::waitForService("/assembled_point_cloud");

    ros::Rate r(updateRate);

    while(ros::ok())
    {
        assemblerService.request.begin = assemblerService.request.end;
        assemblerService.request.end   = ros::Time::now();
        if (assemblerClient.call(assemblerService))
        {
            pointCloud = assemblerService.response.cloud;
                    sensor_msgs::convertPointCloudToPointCloud2(pointCloud, pointCloud2);

            ROS_INFO("Got cloud with %u points\n", assemblerService.response.cloud.points.size());
        }
        else
        {
            ROS_ERROR("Service call for getting assembled laser scan failed\n");
        }

        if (pointCloud2.data.size() > 0)
            pointCloud2Publisher.publish(pointCloud2);

        ros::spinOnce();
        r.sleep();
    }
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195515/multiple-nodes-providing-same-service,-which-one-will-get-through-(many-to-one-services)/) by [ajain](https://answers.ros.org/users/18985/ajain/) on ROS Answers with karma: 281 on 2014-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS does not allow two nodes to provide the same service.

You should instead remap one or both services to a different name, and call them separately.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ajain](https://answers.ros.org/users/18985/ajain/) on 2014-10-21**:
Okay. So if I subscribe to two different services for point_cloud2 from each assembler and then use pcl::concatenatePointCloud() to merge them, will it take care of assembling point clouds with closest timestamps and returning the merged point cloud with latest timestamp?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-21**:
It looks like you're trying to assemble only the most recent scan from each sensor into a composite cloud. Since the primary purpose of the laser assembler is to buffer and assemble multiple scans, it isn't really helping you here.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-21**:
It may be simpler to subscribe to the topics in question and assemble the scans yourself, using the source code for the laser scan assembler as inspiration.